# Proximal operator for ratio of $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$ norms

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I'm interested in computing the proximal operator for the ratio of $\ell_1, \ell_2$ norms
$$
\text{prox}_{\ell_1/\ell_2}(x) = \arg\min_{z} \frac{1}{2}\|z-x\|^2 + \frac{\|z\|_1}{\|z\|_2}.
$$
Does this have a closed form expression? If not, are there any fast computational techniques that can be used to solve this optimization problem?

P.S: This norm comes up in sparse signal recovery and seems to have some nice properties.

Comment: Reading from https://www.math.uci.edu/~jxin/CIS-14-YEX.pdf it seems that this type of penalty term is often accompanied by a non-negativity constraint. Is this the case here?